# How to find out what JavaScript code is slowing down my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some code in my page is making my browser slow after 20-30 min. I need to know which one. What tools can i use to debug this out.

Following js files are being loaded

1. Jquery
2. Jquery ui
3. History
4. Mustache

Yes i **had** settimeout and thought that to be the culprit but alas after removing it too,  it's still a bit slow.

Comment: Post your JS code. Without it it's hard for us to tell you what it is. My guess would be long loops (while or for).

Comment: Psychic code reading powers: ACTIVATE!

Comment: Slowing down your page after 20-30 mins? Sounds like a memory leak to me. Chrome has useful built-in developer tools.

Comment: Another possibility, are you calling `setTimeout` repeatedly? (or JQuery moral equilivant)?

Comment: what javascript libraries are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Google's [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/). It's a Chrome extension.

> Speed Tracer is a tool to help you identify and fix performance
>   problems in your web applications. It visualizes metrics that are
>   taken from low level instrumentation points inside of the browser and
>   analyzes them as your application runs. Speed Tracer is available as a
>   Chrome extension and works on all platforms where extensions are
>   currently supported (Windows and Linux).

Alternatively, you have Yahoo!'s [YUI 2: Profiler](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/).

> The YUI Profiler is a simple, non-visual code profiler for JavaScript.
>   Unlike most code profilers, this one allows you to specify exactly
>   what parts of your application to profile. You can also
>   programmatically retrieve profiling information as the application is
>   running, allowing you to create performance tests YUI Test or other
>   unit testing frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

An addendum to @Julio Santos ' answer

You can use [Dynatrace Ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) which has a good free version of their product